# Loop/array (Java)

Tags: java, loops

I am having some problems in getting a loop to work.  My goal is to create a loop which will allow the user to fill in lottery numbers in several rows (the user may decide how many rows he/she wants to fill out, but it can not be more than a maximum number specified earlier in the code).  So far, my code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LotteryTicket {

    public LotteryRow[] rows;
    public int numberOfRows;
    public Player ticketOwner;

    public LotteryTicket(int maxNumberOfRows) {

        this.rows = new LotteryRow[maxNumberOfRows];
    }

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void fillInTicket() {
        System.out.print("How many rows do you want to fill in? ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        while (n < 1 || n > rows.length) {
            System.out.println("The number of rows must lie between 1 and " + rows.length);
            System.out.print("How many rows do you want to fill in? ");
            n = input.nextInt();
        }
        for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) {
            rows[index].fillInRow();
    }
        numberOfRows = n;
    }
```

When I try to run this in a main-method, and I enter a proper number of rows, I get the error message:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at LotteryTicket.fillInTicket(LotteryTicket.java:24)

Line 24 is the line in which I call upon the fillInRow()-method which I have created in another class, so I suspect the problem lies here.  I know that this method works fine, as I have tried it in a test program.  However, am I not referring correctly to this fillInRow()-method?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created an array with size `maxNumberOfRows`, but you haven't populated it with any objects. It initially just contains null references.

To fix the code, you have to call the `LotteryRow` constructor to create an object and then put a reference to that object in your array. You can fix your code like this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) {
    rows[index] = new LotteryRow();
    rows[index].fillInRow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a new object and place it in the array before you call a method on it.  Java arrays of objects are initialized to all nulls.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `rows`. Yes, you create the Array with `this.rows = new LotteryRow[maxNumberOfRows];` but that does NOT create a  new LotteryRow Object for every Array Entry, so the whole array is filled with `null`. You have to create the LotteryRow Objects by yourself